# Template Placerholder in compose service definition (environment array)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I read [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#create-services-using-templates) that you can use go template placeholder in docker-compose.yml

I have tried various ways for the syntax but I never manage to get the placeholder substituted.

```yaml
version: "3.8"

x-base: &base
    image: "alpine"
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec", "while :; do echo '.'; sleep 5 ; done"]

services:
  foo:
    <<: *base
    environment:
      - TEST1={{.Service.ID}}
      - "TEST2={{.Service.ID}}"
      - 'TEST3={{.Service.ID}}'
      - TEST4="{{.Service.ID}}"
      - TEST5='{{.Service.ID}}'
  bar:
    <<: *base
    environment:
      TEST1: "{{.Service.ID}}"
      TEST2: '{{.Service.ID}}'
```

When I check for the variables, I get this.

```
➜  test docker exec test_foo_1 printenv                  
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=9165fc2da385
TEST1={{.Service.ID}}
TEST2={{.Service.ID}}
TEST3={{.Service.ID}}
TEST4="{{.Service.ID}}"
TEST5='{{.Service.ID}}'
HOME=/root
➜  test docker exec test_bar_1 printenv
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=393430a158d1
TEST1={{.Service.ID}}
TEST2={{.Service.ID}}
HOME=/root
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works only in swarm, not in compose.

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr myhost
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml test
```