# Docker Compose: Increment environment variable

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables

I am locally deploying a full-stack app via Docker Compose and would like to derive the backend and frontend ports from a single environment variable `$PORT`. For example, if `$PORT = 3000`, then the backend port should be `3000` and the frontend port should be `3001`. And if `$PORT = 4000`, then the backend port should be `4000` and the frontend port should be `4001`.

For this, I would like to do something like this in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    ...
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:3000"
  frontend:
    ...
    ports:
      - "$((PORT + 1)):4200"
```

This fails with `ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "frontend"`. Is there a way to achieve this in Docker Compose?

Comment: If you use swarm to run this as stack you can use template placeholder. See the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#create-services-using-templates) and this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64620078/template-placerholder-in-compose-service-definition-environment-array). But as far as I can tell, it only works with swarm. Apart from that, you can just publish the port without mapping. So you just specify 4200 as port and not port mapped-port:4200. Then you need to look them up, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do that. But why don't you set before in your environment those ports variables? For example run before everything:

```
export PORT=3000 #or whatever number you want
export PORT_INC=$(($PORT+1))
```

And then you use like this:

```
ports:
 - "$PORT_INC:4200"
```

Answer (score 2):

Compose only supports a limited set of [environment variable substitutions](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution): `${VARIABLE}`, `${VARIABLE:-default}`, `${VARIABLE:?error message}`, and the latter two options without colons.  You cannot do other substitutions, computation, or shell callouts in Compose.

For this particular case, you can let Docker pick the host port number for you.  This is less predictable than the scheme you describe, but it doesn't require any special setup.  Instead of using two numbers in [`ports:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) just specify the container port number

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    ports:
      - '3000'
  frontend:
    ports:
      - '4200'
```

To find the corresponding host port number, you need to run [`docker-compose port`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/port/)

```sh
docker-compose port frontend 4200
```